# Shared memory Value dissapears from an object

Tags: python, queue, multiprocessing, shared-memory

here is some strange behavior in Python (2.7.9, Windows) I would like to ask an advice about.

I am trying to extend a class with a variable in initialization and I want to share an object of this class between two processes (parent and child). Both of them will use this variable.

This code works fine:

```
# coding: utf-8
from multiprocessing import Process, Value
from time import sleep


class ExQueue(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ExQueue, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.trust_me_this_name_is_unique = Value('L', 0)


def func(ex_queue):
    print 'I am the child process. Is there a parameter: ',
    print hasattr(ex_queue, 'trust_me_this_name_is_unique')

    # this sleep is here to assure no printing overlapping
    sleep(.5)

def main():
    ex_queue = ExQueue()

    print 'I am the parent process. Is there a parameter: ',
    print hasattr(ex_queue, 'trust_me_this_name_is_unique')

    child_process = Process(target=func, args=(ex_queue,))

    child_process.start()

    child_process.join()

    print 'I am the parent process. Is there a parameter: ',
    print hasattr(ex_queue, 'trust_me_this_name_is_unique')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output:

```
I am the parent process. Is there a parameter:  True
I am the child process. Is there a parameter:  True
I am the parent process. Is there a parameter:  True
```

But if `ExQueue` is inherited from `Queue` class (the one from `multiprocessing.queues` module), the trick does not work.

At the beginning add:

```
from multiprocessing.queues import Queue
```

and change

```
class ExQueue(object):
```

to:

```
class ExQueue(Queue):
```

Output will be:

```
I am the parent process. Is there a parameter:  True
I am the child process. Is there a parameter:  False
I am the parent process. Is there a parameter:  True
```

So, in the `ExQueue` example of the child process there is no `trust_me_this_name_is_unique` variable.

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

**UPD:** Works as expected on Mac OS. Variable does not disappear.

### Solution

Thank you, **tdelaney**! Your answer helped a lot!

I added those two methods to the `ExQueue` and it pickles on Windows just fine now:

```
def __getstate__(self):
    state = super(ExQueue, self).__getstate__()
    return state + (self.trust_me_this_name_is_unique,)

def __setstate__(self, state):
    state, self.trust_me_this_name_is_unique = state[:-1], state[-1]
    super(ExQueue, self).__setstate__(state)
```

Still not sure that it's a good approach to inherit from `Queue` at all. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its not a problem with the shared memory value, its the variable on the queue object itself that disappears.

Multiprocessing works differently on machines that implement the *nix forking model verses the Windows create-process model. On *nix, when you create a `multiprocessing` process, the parent process is forked and since the child has as copy-on-write view of the parent's memory space, all of the python objects (including your queue) are in the child space ready to be used.

On Windows, there is no `fork`. A new process is created and the relevant parts of the parent process is pickled, sent to the child and unpickled. This only works for picklable objects so code that works in linux may fail in windows.

If you have an object that isn't natively picklable, you can implement `__getstate__` and `__setstate__` methods that return a pickable subset of the object and rebuild the object from that state. That's been done with the `multiprocessing.Queue` object. It doesn't include your variable in `__getstate__` so the variable isn't included in the child object when its recreated.

An easy solution is to put your data some place else. If that isn't viable, create your own subclass of `multiprocessing.Queue` and write your own `__getstate__` and `__setstate__` methods.

Comment: Thank you. Will look into `__getstate__` and `__setstate__` of the `Queue` now. I do not think it will look nice if I put this additional variable anywhere but in the `ExQueue`. The whole purpose of the `ExQueue` is to behave just like the `Queue` but with `qsize()` working on Mac OS. So, I've basically broke the solution in Windows to make it work in Mac OS. :)

Comment: I added the solution to my question based on overriding those two methods. Works fine! Thanks!